# data is missing from text files

Tags: restart, missing-data

I am using notepad to edit my php files on my desktop, and then suddenly, due to power loss, system restarted. After logging in, every file is not having any data. But, file's  size is same as before (i.e 22kb). could anyone explain this behavior ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried opening it in another editor?

Comment: yes, I tried with word pad and sublime. but, no appearance of data. I restarted my system once again. But, still no data.